# Error when running in test environment ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rspec

I have tried setting up both rspec and minitest testing, but in both instances I'm getting the following error: `ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: No connection pool with id primary found.`

I am able to run `rails db:setup RAILS_ENV=test` without any problems, but running `rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test` doesn't work. It throws the same error (above) that I get when running `rspec .`

Also something that may help, when I run `rails db:create RAILS_ENV=test` I get `Database 'mail_test' already exists`. So the database is definitely there, `mail_test` is the db name defined in my `.env`

I've tried everything, my searches are full of purple links, so any help or suggestions are very welcome!

Edit: Here's the `test` section of my database.yml

`development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: mail_dev
  pool: 5
  username: cbris
  password:
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: mail_test
  pool: 5
  username: cbris
  password:`

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.3.4'

gem 'rails', '5.0'
gem 'puma'
gem 'pg'

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'slim-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'packery-rails'
gem 'font-awesome-sass'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'

gem 'paperclip'
gem 'aws-sdk'
gem 'aws-sdk-rails'

gem 'devise'

gem 'redis'
gem 'sidekiq'
gem 'sidekiq-cron'

gem 'validate_url'
gem 'kaminari'

gem 'httparty'
gem 'smarter_csv'
gem 'chartkick'
gem 'meta_request'
gem 'tinymce-rails'

# Documentation
gem 'rdoc'
gem 'sdoc'

gem 'spring'
gem 'scout_apm'
gem 'annotate'
gem 'faker'

group :development, :test do
  # Testing framework
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'dotenv-rails'
end

group :development do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
end

group :test do
  # Clean db after testing
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'capybara'
end

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

Comment: Can you post your `database.yml` and Gemfile? What database are you using? Did you try `rake db:reset`, `rake db:test:prepare`?

Comment: Thanks for the response! I updated the question with part of the `database.yml`. But note that my development database works fine and that I'm able to run `rails db:setup` under the test environment. I also tried running `db:test:prepare` which ran fine, but I'm still getting the error when running rspec.

Comment: As @xlts asked, can you also post your Gemfile?

Comment: Oh my dad, I hadn't seen the comment about the Gemfile. Just added now. I've tried commenting/re-bundling a few times without success, but I definitely could have missed something.